# Lbq test and ARMA results, Should I include lags?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, autocorrelation, lags

I have a daily return time series, which is stationary(proofed by ADF test) , has no autocorrelation up to lag10(proofed by lbq test with lag10) and has ARCH effect(proofed by LM test). My initial thought is to use GARCH model directly. Rather than the usual procedure: first using ARMA(p,q) to get the residuals, and then fit GARCH to this ARMA residuals.

However, out of curiosity, I still use ARMA(p,q) model loop through (p,q) lags with range [0,1,..,10] to see whether ARMA(0,0) has the smallest AIC among all. After looping through total 121 (p,q) combinations, I find the smallest AIC does NOT belong to ARMA(0,0) model, but ARMA(2,7). Then I check the coef of this ARMA(2,7) model and find many lags included are significant. the two AR lags are both significant at 1% level.

Now, I am quite confused. Based on the result of lbq(10) test, I should use ARMA(0,0). Based on the results of smallest AIC of ARMA models, I should use ARMA(2,7). May I please ask, in this case, should I use ARMA(0,0) or ARMA(2,7)? My preference is to use ARMA(2,7), but how can I explain to others when they ask: why still use ARMA model when lbq test shows no autocorrelation?

Any of your kind thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Please see the code and results below

```
lbqtest(returns,'Lags',1:10)
```

I could also use the following code to only get autocorrelation up to lag10

```
lbqtest(returns,'Lags',10)
```

The p results of lbq(1) till lbq(10) are:

```
p =

0.3425    0.5612    0.4180    0.5356    0.6637    0.7696    0.7770    0.8448    0.8995    0.9198
```

The AIC results of ARMA(2,7) and ARMA(0,0) are

```
  AIC           AR  MA   
-1498.252431    2   7
-1494.028       0   0
```

The estimation result of ARMA(2,7) using R

```
arima(x = returns, order = c(2, 0, 7))

Coefficients:
       ar1      ar2     ma1     ma2      ma3      ma4      ma5     ma6     ma7  intercept
      -1.6786  -0.8756  1.6808  0.8128  -0.1691  -0.1736  -0.1065  0.0419  0.0411    -0.0006
s.e.   0.0381   0.0308  0.0660  0.1044   0.1078   0.1097   0.1082  0.1017  0.0642     0.0015
```